# eleasticsearch runtime error - exception caught on transport layer - java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, elasticsearch, error-handling, runtime-error, elastic-stack

I am currently building a system which can get a list of elasticsearch results however I am getting a recurring error (it happen about ever 30-60s) within servicemix realted to a failed connection. How do I stop this from happening?
Note running ElasticSearch 1.7.1
:

```
2016-12-29 16:05:21,230 | WARN  | elasticsearch[elk][generic][T#19] | transport.netty | 262 -  | [elk] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x9ffdafc0]], closing connection
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)[:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)[:1.8.0_111]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:216)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:787)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:754)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:726)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:220)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:369)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:315)[262:]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$ScheduledNodeSampler.run(TransportClientNodesService.java:348)[262:]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_111]
```

This is the code I believe causing the problem as it the one making the connection to my elastic server.

- the Query just returns everything
- the ImmutableSettings only contains {"name" => "elk"}
- the InetSocketTransportAddress contatins usualy localhost:9300 (however I am also testing bad address to.

  ```
  public static SearchResponse getElkResponse(InetSocketTransportAddress elkHost, HashMap<String, String> settingsMap, QueryBuilder query, int minTimeRange) {
      Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
              .put(settingsMap)
              .build();


      TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(elkHost);
      client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().execute().actionGet(); //not sure why this is need?
      SearchRequestBuilder req = client.prepareSearch()
              .setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1))
              .addSort("@timestamp", SortOrder.ASC)
              .setQuery(query)
              .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("@timestamp").from("now-" + minTimeRange + "m").to("now"))
              .setSize(100);
      SearchResponse res = req.execute().actionGet();
      return res;
  }
  ```

Comment: Are you sure to keep that the ES client library jar is in sync with the version of your cluster?

Comment: @Darth_Vader I am using the correctly ES client library jar related to my ELK stack.

However this doesn't solve how to stop my client from continually trying to connect to a bad address.